# How to replace unwanted characters

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have some hotels that contains characters which are not valie for when i want to insert these hotel names as a file name as file naming doesn't allow /, * or ? and want to know what this error means.

```
text?text
text?text
text**text**
text*text (text)
text *text*
text?
```

I am trying to use an if else statement so that if a hotel name contains any of these characters, then replace them with -. However I am receiving and error stating a dangling ?. I just want to check if I am using the replace correctly for these characters.

```
def hotelNameTrim = hotelName.toString()

if (hotelNameTrim.contains("/"))
{
    hotelNameTrim.replaceAll("/", "-")
}
else if (hotelNameTrim.contains("*"))
{
    hotelNameTrim.replaceAll("*", "-")
}
else if (hotelNameTrim.contains("?"))
{
    hotelNameTrim.replaceAll("?", "-")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replaceAll accepts a regex as a search pattern. * and ? are special characters in regex and need to be escaped with a back slash. Which itself needs to be escaped in a Java string :)

Try this:

```
hotelNameTrim.replaceAll("[\\*\\?/]","-")
```

That will replace all you characters with a dash.